# mod_rewrite index.php?p=$1

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to rewrite index.php?p=page to /page/ but i cant get it to work!

This wont work:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule .* index.php?p=$1 [PT,L]
```

Help please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The back-reference `$1` does not correspond to a group of the left-hand side of your `RewriteRule` (groups are defined using parantheses). Try one of the following:

```
RewriteRule .* index.php?p=$0

# - or -

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?p=$1
```